# DocuSign Powerform: How do I pass Envelope ID in the "Signing Completed" URL?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to retrieve the signer envelope ID after he/she hit the finish button and pass the ID as a parameter in the "Signing Completed" URL. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add MergeField - [[EnvelopeId]] in the Signing Completed - destination Url in your Brand.

Details are available also at:

https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding